# Cron logging output without syslog facility

Tags: linux, cron

Is it possible to redirect the output of cron itself (not the output of the cronjob) to a different file descriptor/file?

I.e., cron is automatically logging to the system log either via syslogd or rsyslogd (depending on what is installed). But if neither of these are installed, how can I still get the logging output, that the jobs are executed on their scheduled time?

The specific case that I have, is that I run cron (in foreground mode) inside a docker container, but cannot redirect (or find for that matter) any cron logs, since there is no syslog facility installed (and I don't want to install any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build cron without syslog.  From the man page: "Naturally this is not relevant if cron was built to use syslog(3)".

Comment: Note that the current cron package (at least on Debian), cannot be build without syslog, without having to modify the source code.
I have added a bugreport with a patch [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=887014)